# DRF: pass a variable from the router to the ViewSet

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I'm working with Django REST Framework and I want to reuse a ViewSet in two places, but to do that I need to pass some information to the ViewSet class.

This is what my urls.py file currently looks like:

```py
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter

from .views import ContentController

router = SimpleRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register("/?", ContentController, basename="content")
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

But what I'd really like to do is something like this:

```py
router.register("/?", ContentController(type="books"), basename="content")
```

This way I can reuse the same `ContentController` in multiple routes, but with a different value for the `type` variable. But the `register` method only seems to take a class, not an instance.

Similar questions are all about URL parameters, and that's not related to my question.

Comment: Simply, this isn't possible because of the way the *routers* are being built